# equivalence of the existence of two integrals

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I was reading a paper and I do not understand how to show the following result: The function $f:\lbrack 0,\infty)\to\lbrack 0,\infty)$ is a strictly monotone increasing and bijective function such that $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)/x=c\in(0,1)$. Define $g:\lbrack 0,\infty)\to\lbrack 0,\infty)$ by
\begin{align*}
g(x)=
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{f(1/x)}&\text{ for }x>0\\
0&\text{ for }x=0
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
and let $d:\lbrack 0,\infty)\to\lbrack 0,\infty)$ be the inverse function of $g$. The paper claims that for any arbitrary but fixed number $\delta>0$ we have
\begin{align*}
\int_0^{\delta}\frac{|d(x)-cx|}{x^2}\text{d}x<\infty
\end{align*}
if and only if for any arbitrary but fixed number $A>0$ we have
\begin{align*}
\int_A^{\infty}\frac{|c-(f(t)/t)|}{t}\text{d}t<\infty
\end{align*}
The justification of the paper is that this follows by first setting $x=g(y)$, then using $g(y)\sim c^{-1}y$ as $y\downarrow 0$ and then setting $t=1/y$. Now $g(y)\sim c^{-1}y$ should follow by the convergence above. If I substitute $x=g(y)$, then
\begin{align*}
\int_0^{\delta}\frac{|d(x)-cx|}{x^2}\text{d}x&=\int_0^{d(\delta)} \frac{|y-cg(y)|}{g(y)^2}g'(y)\text{d}y\\
&=\int_0^{d(\delta)}\frac{|y-c/f(1/y)|}{y^2}f'(1/y)\text{d}y
\end{align*}
Here, I do not see how to continue. Does anyone see how to prove this or where I went wrong?